# Which is more performant for merging two sequences into one: `seq1 ++ seq2` or Seq(seq1, seq2).flatten

Tags: scala

Topic.
I know ++ can run into some very slow performance issues when dealing with very large data sequences.
Is Seq(seq1, seq2).flatten any better?
Or, is there a third option that i'm not considering, like union, concat, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on the underlying **Sequence** `Seq` is a very failed abstraction you can't do anything safe with it except for common methods like `map`. In any case, I would expect both alternatives to have similar performance, but you may want to benchmark to be sure. - My advice would be to stop using `Seq` and use a colelction appropitae for your use case.

Comment: try to avoid seq concatenating. Seq flatten is not better, you should think more about what *data structure* in your case is Seq. `Seq` is trait for abstract sequences, it can be linked list, then concatenating is slow, or it can be some buffer `ArrayBuffer` for example and you can use `addAll` witch is faster then `++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heed [sbt-jmh](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh) advice

> "Trust no one, bench everything."

thus

```
sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 5 -f 2 -t 1 bench.So60643849"
```

where

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So60643849 {
  val size = 1000000
  val seq = Seq.fill(size)(42)

  @Benchmark def ++(): Seq[Int] = seq ++ seq
  @Benchmark def flatten(): Seq[Int] = Seq(seq, seq).flatten
}
```

gives with Scala 2.13.1 which has by default `List` as concrete implementation of `Seq`

```
[info] Benchmark               Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
[info] So60643849.$plus$plus  thrpt   20  94.436 ± 4.928  ops/s
[info] So60643849.flatten     thrpt   20  52.070 ± 6.549  ops/s
```

therefore `seq1 ++ seq2` seems faster. Also, IMO, intention seems clearer than `Seq(seq1, seq2).flatten`.

Comment: It is worth to mention that this test is meaningless since actually you are testing **List** concatenation not **Seq** and is impossible to test **Seq** since it is abstract.